# Hiding organizations in general list

Tags: ckan

Is it possible to hide a given organiazation so it isn't shown at the organization list at http://demo.ckan.org/organization (and in equivalent API methods, such as "organization_list) but shown when you access directlty to the Org URL (e.g. http://demo.ckan.org/organization/winterfell)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, but you could write a plugin to do this by using the IActions plugin interface to override the organization_list action. Just call the _group_or_org_list() function (like the default organization_list() function does), but filter out certain organizations before returning the result.

There may be other places where you'd want to hide the organization as well, e.g. in activity streams. The same technique should work.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you make changes in database.
Set "state" of the organization from "group" table to "draft" in your ckan_default database.

or use following script:

```
UPDATE "group"
SET state = 'draft'
WHERE "group".name = ‘winterfell’;
```

It will be still accessible using http://demo.ckan.org/organization/winterfell

To make it visible again use:

```
UPDATE "group"
SET state = 'active'
WHERE "group".name = ‘winterfell’;
```